# php / add months to DateTime returns bad date

Tags: php, datetime

Strange behavior about this code :

```
var_dump((new \DateTime())->createFromFormat("j-M-Y", "30-Nov-2015")->add(new \DateInterval('P3M')));
```

Will return

```
class DateTime#2 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(19) "2016-03-01 15:13:32"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(14) "Africa/Algiers"
}
```

And not the expected ...

```
class DateTime#2 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(19) "2016-02-29 15:13:32"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(14) "Africa/Algiers"
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: That's the result I would expect.

Comment: This question cannot be answered, because what you expect it to do based on your arbitrary rules does conflict with the rules the language works and most people would expect it to work. So unless you can/want to rephrase your question I don't see how this can possibly be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example

```
var_dump((new \DateTime())->createFromFormat("j-M-Y", "30-Nov-2015")->add(new \DateInterval('P3M')));
```

cannot be thought of as "add 3 months to the last day of the month", but instead "add 3 months to the 30th day of the month". Since February 2016 has 29 days instead of 28, 30 days after the first of the month is March 1st. Similarly, note that

```
var_dump((new \DateTime())->createFromFormat("j-M-Y", "30-Nov-2015")->add(new \DateInterval('P2M')));
```

lands on the 30th of January rather than the 31st.